# TSQL Update DATETIME Minutes and Seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been staring at this for quite a while and can't figure out how to go about doing it.  I don't really have any code to post because I haven't even gotten close to figuring it out yet and everything I come up with just doesn't make any sense.

Anyways, we have an application that collects data every 5 minutes based on the max(readtime) in the table (but also will only show real values if the time is a multiple of 5 and is at :00.000 seconds.)  For the most part, this is fine, but sometimes the data will get out of sync and cause a bunch of 0 values in our table.

Currently, we've just been going in, grabbing the latest readtime, and hardcoding the new date that we'd like to use.  I'm looking for a script I can use to automate this.  For the purposes of this question, we can use GETDATE().

```
DECLARE @readtime DATETIME = GETDATE()  --2011-08-09 08:51:19.237
             -- I want it to look like    2011-08-09 08:50:00.000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Round down to nearest 5 minute.

```
DECLARE @readtime DATETIME = 
    DATEADD(minute, 5*FLOOR(DATEDIFF(minute, 0, GETDATE())/5.0), 0)
```

Comment: What is the 5*Floor / 5.0 doing in this case?

Comment: @Davin - Minutes is divided by 5.0 to get a float value that is rounded down to the nearest integer using `floor`. That value is multiplied by 5 to get back to minutes again.

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

It basically checks minutes to be divisible by 5, seconds by 6 and ms by 1000, and if they aren't it subtracts the remainder from each:

```
DECLARE @dt datetime = '2011-08-09 08:51:19.237'

SELECT DATEADD(
                MILLISECOND, 
                -(DATEPART(MILLISECOND, @dt) % 1000), 
                DATEADD(
                        SECOND, 
                        -(DATEPART(second, @dt) % 60), 
                        DATEADD(
                                minute, 
                                -(DATEPART(minute, @dt) % 5), @dt )
                        )
                )
```

**Output:**

`2011-08-09 08:50:00.000`

Comment: @Lieven - not always, but it's nice when it is.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I'm not sure if the guy deleted it or if I just can't find it but this also worked.  

    DECLARE @readtime DATETIME =    DATEADD(minute, 5*ROUND(DATEDIFF(minute, 0, GETDATE())/5, 0), 0)

Comment: @tom - I guess it was my answer. Changed to use `floor` instead because round would go to nearest 5 min up or down. It is back now.